# Best way to refresh accessToken once

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, locking, jwt

From my ASP.NET Core Application i'd like to consume an API which is secured by some kind of token authentication .
As the process of getting a token takes quite long (and i think it's bad design to do it multiple times unnecessarily) i want to make sure that the API Call which gets me a token is executed just once if there is no token or it is expired.

This was my approch:
I created a new service and registered it as singleton

```
   services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();
```

The service itself looks like this

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private object _lock = new object();
    private JwtSecurityToken _accessToken;

    public Service()
    {
        GetNewToken();
    }

    public async Task<object> GetSomething()
    {
        EnsureAccessTokenValidity();
        //Do the api call with the token
    }

    public async Task<object> GetSomethingDifferent()
    {
        EnsureAccessTokenValidity();
        //Do the api call with the token
    }

    private void EnsureAccessTokenValidity()
    {

        if (_accessToken.ValidTo > DateTime.UtcNow) return;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_accessToken.ValidTo > DateTime.UtcNow) return;
            GetNewToken(); 
        }
    }

    private void GetNewToken()
    {
        //Get a new _accessToken 
    }
}
```

It seems to work but i think there should be a more elegant way to manage this. How do you guys handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

hey @askingdumbquestions, welcome to the community

Your initial approach makes sense but has a few drawback:

1. There a regular performance hit on a request that encounters the expired token since it will be fetched within the same process.
2. Since request can be processed in parallel - it could be the case that multiple requests encounter the expired token and go fetch a new one. Depending on the amount of request that are running in parallel this could easily take down you potentially slow authentication service - not something to be desired! YES: this could be solved by a simple Mutex around the experiation check and fetching of the token. This will lead to a lot of locking and tasks waiting for each other and for the one tasks that has to fetch the token! (All request will/must be blocked while to token is fetched).

But there is another way: You fetch your token the first time your `Service` is constructed and then start a asynchronous task which fetches / refreshes the token a few minutes before it expires! This will ensure you always have a valid token ready and puts away the need for expensive and error-prone thread synchronization and removes the latency spike for those request that would other vice have to fetch a token.

Let me know if this was helpful or you need more detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cache for that. Set its policy's `AbsoluteExpiration` to `ValidTo` (ideally with a small offset) and it'll be automatically evicted once it's expired. Something like:

```
private readonly ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;

public T GetToken()
{
    if (!_cache.Contains("token"))
    {
        GetAndCacheNewToken();
    }

    return _cache.Get("token") as T;
}

public void GetAndCacheNewToken()
{
    T token;

    // Get your token.

    _cache.Add(
        "token", 
        token, 
        new CacheItemPolicy() {AbsoluteExpiration = token.ValidTo.AddSeconds(-1)});
}
```

I labeled the token's type as `T`, because I don't know what type it is in your app.

Comment: I would consider this a bad solution in the sense, that it introduces caching into the equation which comes with it's own share of problem like cache invalidation. In this case it also offer almost no improvement to having a singleton service which manages the lifetime of the access token itself... Delegating the token lifetime to the caching layer which has an absolute expiration can also lead to a problem (what if the token expires before the cache invalidates it?)

Comment: It doesn't introduce a new service for managing lifetime, but utilizes an existing one - caching. Secondly, the token won't expire before the cache invalidates it, that's what the absolute expiration is for, and it's additionally safeguarded by the 1-second (implementation specific tbh) offset.

Comment: yes, but this assumes that there is a request coming in within the second between the moment that the cache expires and the token expires. Also should multiple requests encounter the same expired cache item, they will all fetch a new token in parallel which depending on how many times that happens and how many instances of your app are running can easily take down a not-so-scalable identity provider...

Comment: Additionally it introduces static context into your application which kills all hopes of  having any repeatable tests on the service that utilizes caching...